# WordPress remove sidebar from specific page and make them full width

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using the Hueman theme in WordPress. And I want to exclude the sidebar from all my pages except for the homepage.

Problem is the the pages where there is no sidebar have a blank space for where it used to be. I want my content to go over that blank space.
I can't remove the blank space without removing it from the home page aswell.

Can this be done by adding some code into a custom template?

Sorry if this is unclear. I can add images if needed.

Edit: Screenshots.

[image]

This is my homepage in the red box is the sidebar which is supposed to be only visible at the homepage.

Whenever I go to another page that sidebar place is still visible, I want my text to go over it oer be centered.
[image]
Basically this grey box here (marked with red) has to be white and my content has to be able to go over it.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: add screenshots

Comment: Added screenshots, hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(!is_page('page_id')) { ?>
---- dynamic sidebar code ---
<?php } ?>
```

Also add your div in the same condition to show a particluar page full width and other with sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Wait I'm an idiot.
It's all the way down where you edit a page.
Select layout and choose for 1 column. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

put below condition in the page where you dont want side bar

```
<?php if(!is_page('[YOUR PAGE ID]')) { ?>
    YOUR SIDEBAR CODE GOES HERE
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Display widget is useful in which you can manually select on which page you have to display sidebar from widget section.

[Display Widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/)